# Shotgun film mic suggestions

Tags: shotgun, microphone, film, budget, suggestions

Hi everyone, just a quick questions on any suggestions for a good, rugged, film shotgun mic, such as the Rode NTG-1 and alternatives costing upto around 500 dollars... 
Outdoor filming.

Thanks for any contributions in advance!

Comment: You're in the States right, Chris? 

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SENNHEISER-MKH415-same-specs-as-MKH416-SHOTGUN-CONDENSER-MICROHPONE-XLR-CABLE-/310683398468?pt=US_Pro_Audio_Microphones&hash=item48562c7144

Comment: unfortunately bud, i'm in Perth Western Australia, but this sennheiser is a deal and half! Thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's for dialogue I'd try and buy a secondhand MKH416. If you had to buy new right away then a K6/ME66. I honestly don't think anything below these is worth owning as they all lack sensitivity and are too noisy. If this wasn't an option I'd hire instead.

Comment: well rode ntg3 blows k6/me66 away..actually ntg3 is more in mkh416 league, they sound very similar, its also a rf bias condenser so its immune to moisture.

Comment: I've got nothing against the NTG3 and think it's a good alternative. It's a slightly higher price point than the ME66, but my main point being that you get what you pay for and perhaps it's not worth going below that level, NTG3 included ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would also go for something used with that budget, like a MKH416 or possibly NTG-3.